# add layout to mainwindow and set size policy options

Tags: c++, qt, layout

C++: I have a layout created in my MainWindow class in Qt which holds a button, combo box, and label.  It's a QHBoxLayout.  I want to use setLayout to make this the layout for the MainWindow, but I get an error saying it already has its layout set.  How can I set my QHBoxLayout to be the layout for the MainWindow?

Once I have it set, how do I programatically change the sizePolicy for the layout so that the widgets will:  (a) resize with the window, (b) stay fixed, (c) stay fixed vertically and expand horizontally, (d) stay fixed horizontally and expand vertically?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to do it programmatically (+read docs) and you will get an answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That is actually how I am doing it when I receive the error. In the MainWindow constructor, I make pointers to the widgets, create a QHBoxLayout, add the widgets, then set the layout with this->setLayout(layout), where layout is a pointer to my QHBoxLayout.